# Distributing a Play 2.0.1 framework application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

The latest version of play (2.0.1 I think) does not provide a means to pack an application in a web archive. Is there any way to pack an application for distribution?

Comment: play dist creates a standalone package, however that is not a war

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module for WAR, from [its announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/war/play-framework/vYGI-JhT_lE/9gnP4nHjj7AJ)

> Play2War is a module for Play framework 2 to package your apps into
>   standard WAR packages:
>   https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/
>
> Look at http://servlet30.play-war.cloudbees.net/ for an example
>   (JBoss7 @Cloudbees).
>
> As previous versions, Play2War plugin only supports Servlet 3.x
>   containers, with async request/response model (Tomcat7, JBoss 7, Jetty
>   8, ...)
>
> v0.3.2 fixes issue with duplicated entries in WAR file (does not fix
>   the same issue for "dist" task).
>
> Remember, this plugin is still in alpha version and project needs
>   testers (Weblogic, Websphere, ...)
>   https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/How-to-help
>
> Damien

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for that, called [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin). However, pay attention, some features of native play won't be accessible from a a servlet-container. The plugin site displays a compatibility matrix showing current status and planned improvements.

As said by ron in the comment above, you can use `play dist` in the play console to produce a standalone jvm application. It's the recommended option for deployment.